CFLAFGS filtering out -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
I have the CFLAGS as mentioned below with MAKE_VARS
CFLAGS="-Os -pipe -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -mfloat-abi=soft  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro  -I/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/usr/include -I/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/include " CXXFLAGS="-Os -pipe -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -mfloat-abi=soft  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro  -I/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/usr/include -I/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/include " LDFLAGS="-L/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib -L/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm_softfp-gcc-10.3-linux-4.19-glibc-2.32-binutils-2.36.1/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib -znow -zrelro "
and these are getting passed to the all the Makefiles in the build and mainly with -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 getting errors
to resolve and filter out mainly -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 from the CFLAGS or LD_FLAGS which solution we can follow
i tried with below solution , that didn't help
MAKE_FLAGS := $(filter-out -Wformat,$(MAKE_FLAGS))
MAKE_FLAGS := $(filter-out -Werror=format-security,$(MAKE_VARS))
Any other methodologies we can follow to solve it?
i tried with below solution , that didn't help
MAKE_FLAGS := $(filter-out -Wformat,$(MAKE_FLAGS))
MAKE_FLAGS := $(filter-out -Werror=format-security,$(MAKE_VARS))
Any other methodologies we can follow to solve it?

How is it that you are not in control of the CFLAGS, so that you're considering filtering out instead of not putting in the unwanted flags in the first place?

I'm not saying that there are no plausible reasons for that.  Those particular flags look like some that rpmbuild puts in by default, for example. But how best to avoid them depends on how you got them.

On the other hand, have you considered that the errors you are getting might be something to fix instead of to ignore?
